Why do two interfaces have the same ID even if one of them inherits from another interface?
Take a look at this code:
pragma solidity >=0.8.26;

import { IERC165 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol";

interface IFoo1 is IERC165 {
    function myFunction() external pure returns (bool);
}

interface IFoo2 {
    function myFunction() external pure returns (bool);
}

contract Implementation {
    function option1() external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return type(IFoo1).interfaceId;
    }

    function option2() external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return type(IFoo2).interfaceId;
    }
}

Both option1 and option2 return the same value: 0xc3780a3a. But why? IFoo1 contains an additional function, namely, the supportsInterface function defined in IERC165.

It actually doesn't include inherited functions, mentioned in the feature PR
There is also a discussion regarding this in the comments of this same PR

